# Como puedo reproducir sonido en dos dispositivos de audio diferentes? (auriculares y parlantes de mi pc)

Tags: c#, .net

Deseo que, cuando se lance un evento en mi aplicación se reproduzca un sonido tanto en un auricular (si es que lo tengo conectado) y en los parlantes de mi pc.
Estuve probando con WaveOut pero no me funciono.
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Renato, seria de gran ayuda y un punto de partida si puedes mostrarnos que has intentado con WaveOut.. saludos y suerte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El camino que estabas tomando con el `WaveOut` es correcto, quizas lo que te estaria faltanto es definir la propiedad `DeviceNumber`

[How to play sound in many devices at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011515/how-to-play-sound-in-many-devices-at-the-same-time)

[Play a sound in a specific device with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868966/play-a-sound-in-a-specific-device-with-c-sharp)

```
 var waveOut = new WaveOut();
 waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
 WaveStream waveReader = new WaveFileReader(fileName);

 waveOut.Init(waveReader);
 waveOut.Play();
```

Tambien recomendaria le des una mirada a [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

[Send sound to different audio devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422273/send-sound-to-different-audio-devices)

hace uso de ejemplo suando varias librerias de audio y tienen en cuenta el device de output